# PHP: Skipping to a position given by strpos()

Tags: php

If I have a string position that I derived with `strpos()`, how would I skip to that position? I am using a function that needs to start at the position, or at the start of the next line.

How would I do this? Speed is a factor.

Comment: What is "skip to a position" for your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can skip to any character in a string with

```
$string[$index]
```

but I'm not sure what you mean by skip to position?

@strap is correct if skip to position means split string at position.

Comment: This is valid if you are looking to return a single character in the string, +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

`substr()` lets you pull a part of a string. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

From the manual:

```
<?php
$rest = substr("abcdef", 0, -1);  // returns "abcde"
$rest = substr("abcdef", 2, -1);  // returns "cde"
$rest = substr("abcdef", 4, -4);  // returns false
$rest = substr("abcdef", -3, -1); // returns "de"
?>
```

So you can use your `strpos` as an input to the second argument. Leave the third argument blank if you want till the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $new_string = substr( $string, strpos($string, 'a') );
```

The above would assign the string starting at the first 'a' to the end to the variable $new_string